# Lambda Cognito - Password Change - Invalid Access Token

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am trying to change user password using Lambda function, which I have granted full access over Congnito. Method and parameters are as following.

```
Method: cognitoidentityserviceprovider.changePassword 
Paramter: 
{
                        AccessToken: data.AccessToken, /* required */
                        PreviousPassword:  data.PreviousPassword, /* required */
                        ProposedPassword:  data.ProposedPassword /* required */
                    }
```

The user is an authenticated user with a valid access token in my application. I get the access token from the user authentication data and send it with the rest of the parameters to lambda.

For some reason ( which I don't know :D ) the changePassword methods return back with an error as following

```
code:"NotAuthorizedException"
message:"Invalid Access Token"
```

Comment: Are you authenticated in lambda?

Comment: The user is authenticated and has a valid access token through node.js in the server. I don't do any additional authentication in lambda for the user.  Shouldn't a valid access token be enough ?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As seen here, I would use the admin Auth Api. Send the call with REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH as the Auth Type to get new tokens. then grab the access token and try again.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html

```
    var params = {
  AuthFlow: USER_SRP_AUTH | REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH | REFRESH_TOKEN | CUSTOM_AUTH | ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH | USER_PASSWORD_AUTH, /* required */
  ClientId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  UserPoolId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  AnalyticsMetadata: {
    AnalyticsEndpointId: 'STRING_VALUE'
  },
  AuthParameters: {
    '<StringType>': 'STRING_VALUE',
    /* '<StringType>': ... */
  },
  ClientMetadata: {
    '<StringType>': 'STRING_VALUE',
    /* '<StringType>': ... */
  },
  ContextData: {
    HttpHeaders: [ /* required */
      {
        headerName: 'STRING_VALUE',
        headerValue: 'STRING_VALUE'
      },
      /* more items */
    ],
    IpAddress: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
    ServerName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
    ServerPath: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
    EncodedData: 'STRING_VALUE'
  }
};
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminInitiateAuth(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```